# VisualSVN How to roll back the revision number?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

The company I work in has suffered a major server failure. During this failure the SVN Repository was lost. But there is still hope !
We have an **old backup** of the repository which I've managed to successfully restore using VisualSVN.

The problem I'm facing now is that I can't update / commit pre-failure checkedout folders. The reason for this problem is that for instance: a local folder has a **revision number of 2361**, while the repository itself holds a **revision number of 2290**, which is older.

Is there a way to deal with this issue ? Can I some how change the revision numbers on either the local copy or the server copy?

**A few points:**

- I'm using TortoiseSVN 1.6.6.
- I can checkout folders from the repo and the connection is active.
- I've picked one of my folders and used the **Relocate** option on it. This helped me see that there is something wrong with the revision number
- I've experimented a bit with the merge option but this lead me now where special. (I'm open for suggestions )

Thank you for your time,

Ita

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to checkout your project into a new working copy, then use whatever tools that you have to move the changes into the new working copy.

You simply can't turn back the revision number. Your current working copy potentially contains changes that aren't in the older backup of the repository, and the working copy doesn't treat them as 'different from the repository'.

As your repository was lost, so was any chance of reconciling your current working copy.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to avoid this solution but as it seems it wasn't that bad. 

I've used this line :
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('DIR /B /AD /S *.svn*') DO RMDIR /S /Q "%%G"

in a batch file to help me get rid of the old .svn folders that resided in the folders I needed to move.
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Oh, I didn't imply that you needed to 'move', but that certainly is an approach. I would 've used Beyond Compare or something similar to get a visual on what exactly I'm doing. But if everything worked out, more power to ya!

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the newest revision of the restored backup into a working copy. do an svn export of and old working copy and simply copy all files/folders onto the previously checkout working copy. Than do an svn add if needed and commit. This should summ all changes.

Comment: It's possible that the current working copy contains changes that hadn't been committed yet.

Comment: Yes that's exactly the idea of my suggestions, cause it will take everything which is not checked in etc. (may be you have to check --force option of the export command).